# Multiply subset of columns by values in second data frame using match in R

Tags: r, match

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
data <- read.table(text="
  Country A B
1 FRA     1 2
2 GER     2 1
", header=TRUE)
```

I have a reference data frame which looks like this

```
ref <- read.table(text="
  Names Values
1     A      5
2     B     10
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to multiply each column by corresponding row in Ref having same Name (while retaining non-numeric rows without a match)

the result should be this

```
> result
  Country  A  B
1 FRA      5 20
2 GER     10 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subset the columns of interest ('nm1'), multiply with the replicated corresponding 'Values' of 'ref' after `match`ing the column names with the 'Names' column, and update those columns

```
nm1 <- c("A", "B")
result <- data
result[nm1] <-data[nm1] * ref$Values[match(nm1, ref$Names)][col(data[nm1])]
result
#  Country  A  B
#1     FRA  5 20
#2     GER 10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also be an option. It's a little long though and the above suggested answer might be better.

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(
  Country = c("FRA", "GER"),
  A = c(1,2),
  B = c(2,1)
)

ref <- data.frame(
  Names = c("A", "B"),
  Values = c(5, 15)
)

data %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B), values_to = c("Value"), names_to = "Names") %>% 
left_join(ref, by = "Names") %>% 
mutate(New_Value = Value * Values) %>% 
select(-Value, -Values) %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = Names, values_from = New_Value)
```